# Loop through all comments for a substring

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm writing a program that would go over a list of strings containing artists' names and compare it to all the comments on a Reddit submission. It stops after finding one match or doesn't work at all(even with simple test strings), can you point me to the bug? Including the Reddit parts excluding authentication.

```
submission = reddit.submission(id='75lnoo') # Topic about Eminem, lots of mentions of him
submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0)  # Stores all the comments
comments = submission.comments.list()
artists_list = ['Eminem', 'Drake'] # Sample list
for comment in comments:
    for artist in artists_list:
        if artist.lower() in comment.body.lower():
            print(comment.permalink() + ' - ' + artist)
```

Would only print one thing when there should be plenty of matches

> /r/Music/comments/75lnoo/eminem_rips_donald_trump_in_bet_hip_hop_awards/do894hp - Eminem

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: Indentation fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran the code locally on my machine I got a lot of results for `Eminem` and none for `Drake`.  My guess since this threw me off at first was it took a while for it to get the second results after the first. It could be that you are terminated the program early thinking all results are printed?

Here a direct copy-paste:

```
 import praw

 reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = '',
                 client_secret= '',
                 user_agent= '',
                 username = '',
                 password = '')

submission = reddit.submission(id='75lnoo')
submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0)  # Stores all the comments
comments = submission.comments.list()
artists_list = ['Eminem', 'Drake'] # Sample list
print(artists_list)
for comment in comments:
for artist in artists_list:
    if artist.lower() in comment.body.lower():
        print(comment.permalink() + ' - ' + artist)
```

Comment: Oh okayy, I believe the issue with my code was a part that attempted to filter out all the empty spaces in the artists list with a `artists_list = filter(None, artists_list)`, matches fine without it, will just need to find another way to filter them.

Comment: Ah I see, the first parameter of filter() needs to a functions that returns True or False which is then applied to the list, i.e. the second parameter. The output of the function is a list of elements which made the function return True.